# Inheriting QListWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog that I am using to select from a list of items displayed from an SQL table.  Once an item is selected I need to go back to the table and read all the data for the selected item. I want to add the SQL ID to the WidgetItem.

I have created a class that inherits from QListWidgetItem.  All I want to do is add an integer ID.  I am getting all sorts of compile errors related to Meta Objects.

Here is the header:

```
#ifndef MYLISTWIDGETITEM_H
#define MYLISTWIDGETITEM_H

#include <QListWidget>
#include <QListWidgetItem>

class MyListWidgetItem : public QListWidgetItem
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MyListWidgetItem(QListWidget *parent = 0);
  explicit MyListWidgetItem(QString content, QListWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MyListWidgetItem();

  int getSqlTblEntryKey() const;
  void setSqlTblEntryKey(int);

private:
  int sqlTblEntryKey;

};

#endif // MYLISTWIDGETITEM_H
```

And this is the source"

```
#include "mylistwidgetitem.h"

MyListWidgetItem::MyListWidgetItem(QListWidget *parent) :
  QListWidgetItem(parent)
{
}

MyListWidgetItem::MyListWidgetItem(QString content, QListWidget *parent) :
  QListWidgetItem(content, parent)
{
}

MyListWidgetItem::~MyListWidgetItem()
{

}

int MyListWidgetItem::getSqlTblEntryKey() const
{
  return sqlTblEntryKey;
}

void MyListWidgetItem::setSqlTblEntryKey(int value)
{
  sqlTblEntryKey = value;
}
```

I'm getting these errors:

> 10:43:35: Running steps for project LEAPv1.7.1...
>
> 10:43:35: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>
> 10:43:35: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
>
> C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
>         cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\LEAPV1.7.1.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_YES_DEBUG_OUTPUT -DQT_MULTIMEDIAWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"....\SFML-2.1\include" -I"....\Progra~2\Carmenta\Carmen~1\include" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtMultimediaWidgets" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtOpenGL" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtMultimedia" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtSerialPort" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtSql" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtNetwork" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtGui" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\GLENNP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mylistwidgetitem.obj.1304.109.jom
>
> mylistwidgetitem.cpp
>
> C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DWIN32
>   -DQT_YES_DEBUG_OUTPUT -DQT_MULTIMEDIAWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_MSC_VER=1600 -D_WIN32 -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/mkspecs/win32-msvc2010 -IC:/Qt-Projects/LEAP/LEAPv1.7.1 -IC:/SFML-2.1/include -IC:/Progra~2/Carmenta/Carmen~1/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtMultimediaWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtOpenGL -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtMultimedia -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtSerialPort -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtSql -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtNetwork -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/msvc2010_opengl/include/QtCore -I. ....\Qt-Projects\LEAP\LEAPv1.7.1\mylistwidgetitem.h -o
>   debug\moc_mylistwidgetitem.cpp
>         cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc /Fddebug\LEAPV1.7.1.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_YES_DEBUG_OUTPUT -DQT_MULTIMEDIAWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"....\SFML-2.1\include" -I"....\Progra~2\Carmenta\Carmen~1\include" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtMultimediaWidgets" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtOpenGL" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtMultimedia" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtSerialPort" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtSql" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtNetwork" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtGui" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\GLENNP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\addressdialog.obj.1304.125.jom
>
> addressdialog.cpp
>
> cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189
>   -EHsc /Fddebug\LEAPV1.7.1.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_YES_DEBUG_OUTPUT -DQT_MULTIMEDIAWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"....\SFML-2.1\include" -I"....\Progra~2\Carmenta\Carmen~1\include" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtMultimediaWidgets" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtOpenGL" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtMultimedia" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtSerialPort" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtSql" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtNetwork" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtGui" -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"....\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\GLENNP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mylistwidgetitem.obj.1304.390.jom
>
> moc_mylistwidgetitem.cpp
>
> debug\moc_mylistwidgetitem.cpp(63) : error C2039: 'staticMetaObject' :
>   is not a member of 'QListWidgetItem'
>
> ```
>     c:\qt\qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\qtwidgets\qlistwidget.h(61)
> ```
>
> : see declaration of 'QListWidgetItem'
>            jom: C:\Qt-Testing\LEAPv1.7.1\Makefile.Debug [debug\moc_mylistwidgetitem.obj] Error 2
>
> debug\moc_mylistwidgetitem.cpp(70) : error C2227: left of
>   '->metaObject' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>
> debug\moc_mylistwidgetitem.cpp(70) : error C2227: left of
>   '->dynamicMetaObject' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>
> debug\moc_mylistwidgetitem.cpp(78) : error C2039: 'qt_metacast' : is
>   not a member of 'QListWidgetItem'
>
> ```
>     c:\qt\qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\qtwidgets\qlistwidget.h(61)
> ```
>
> : see declaration of 'QListWidgetItem'
>            debug\moc_mylistwidgetitem.cpp(83) : error C2039: 'qt_metacall' : is not a member of 'QListWidgetItem'
>
> ```
>     c:\qt\qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\include\qtwidgets\qlistwidget.h(61)
> ```
>
> : see declaration of 'QListWidgetItem'
>            jom: C:\Qt-Testing\LEAPv1.7.1\Makefile [debug] Error 2
>
> 10:43:38: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
>   exited with code 2.
>
> Error while building/deploying project LEAPv1.7.1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3
>   MSVC2010 OpenGL 32bit) When executing step 'Make'
>
> 10:43:38: Elapsed time: 00:03.

I don't have a clue what to do.  I just wanted to add an integer to the class so I don't have to maintain another table internally.  Obviously I don't understand what I am doing here!

Answer (score 8):

Remove `Q_OBJECT` macro from your class. You should only use `Q_OBJECT` in classes which derive from `QObject`. `QListWidgetItem` does not derive from `QObject` so `MyListWidgetItem` doesn't derive from `QObject`.